basic question about meager and comeager sets.
In a completely metrizable space, the Baire category theorem holds so a subset cannot be meager and comeager. If our space is not completely metrizable, then could a set be both meager and comeager?

A simple example is that any subset of the rationals $\mathbb Q$ (which is not completely metrizable) is a countable union of nowhere-dense subsets (the one-point sets) so is meager, and the same goes for its complement.

oh thanks, this makes complete sense
